# How to determine the Public IP address for a Tinc VPN to work?

Tags: vpn, tinc

Me and my 3 friends want to connect our computers through a VPN with each other. We thought of using Tinc for our purpose. While I understood most of the part of setting up but what I'm unable to get is the Public IP of my computer. Tinc requires the Public IP of at least one of the hosts for it to initiate connection. I tried going on the internet to find my Public IP but different websites are giving me different results. What should I put in the configuration file for my Public IP?

**EDIT**

Specifically we have a Raspberry Pi which is with me currently. We want everyone of us to be able to access the device. I installed Tinc on the Pi and then I don't know what to do for the Public IP. I'm using SSH to control the Raspberry Pi. So please tell me how to find the public address of the Pi through SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your Public IP address by using one of these methods.

1. Open Google and type "What's my IP". Google displays your Public IP address in the result.
2. Go to [What Is My IP](https://www.whatismyip.com/) to find out your Public IP.
3. Since you're using the command line, I would recommend this: execute `curl ipinfo.io/ip` command and your Public IP will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If your router does not reboot, you public IP is not supposed to change. So, if you go on a website like [this one](http://www.mon-ip.com), you should have your public IP displayed.